# Imacros: can't click an anchor which don't have href attribute

Tags: click, href, imacros

I'm using Imacros to click on this button:

```
<a id="button6685628" class="p-button" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);">
<span>Submit</span></a>
```

using this Imacros code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:button6685628
```

When running the Imacros code the button only gets selected but not clicked, 
So please, anyone know how to make this click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Submit`. If it doesn't work maybe it is a javascript event triggered button and if you disable javascript the script clicks it.